# keycloak version to use with (react, spring boot, postgres)

Tags: reactjs, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak

what is the best version of keycloak to use with spring boot as backend and react as frontend and I can setup easily with a postgres database, I've tested the latest version 19.0.1 but I couldn't set it up with react and spring boot and it doesn't take the postgres DB I specified in env variables.

can you please suggest me the best version to use and some tutorials, videos or articles to learn more about it and how to implement it in production.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you **don't use Keycloak Spring adapters**, [it is deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

The latest Keycloak version works perfectly. Maybe you just misconfigured or use the wrong libs.

For client (react app), pick a library from [certified list](https://openid.net/developers/certified/)

For resource-server (Spring REST API), use either:

- [`spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) (but require quite some Java conf)
- [`spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (a lot is configurable from properties, including CORS and roles mapping)

Regarding the connection to Postgres, maybe should you return to the doc and read more carefully.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, I managed to implement keycloak with ReactJs project but in backend I am using Spring Boot microservices, and I don't know what security approach to use, login user from React and send token to api gateway just to verify the token and pass the user id to other services alone or I need to pass the token to each service and verify the token in each service.

Comment: You forward authorization header and configure your resource-server micro-services as explained in the links of the answer. Second is the easiest: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication

Answer (score -1):

I'd recomend using the keycloak-spring-boot-starter.
Here is an article on how to set it up: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak

I would also recomend to always use the most recent version. Especially for a security tool like keycloak. If it doesn't work with the tutorial just set it up in the version the tutorial references and then migrate to a newer version step by step using migration guides.

Comment: [Keycloak adapters are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). See my answer for alternatives.